# All months total of CheckList

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to build this type of query in SQLServer for my report but for branches.

### Branch_Master

Branch_ID
Branch_Name

### CheckList_Master

CheckList_ID
CheckList_Name

### CheckList_Detail

CheckList_ID
Branch_ID
Chk_Value
ResponseDate

Now I want to pass only the month and year and it should do something like the following. **Note: I have taken this query from oracle forum for the requirement of MONTHS but i want BRANCHES. Also note for example if i have 12 branches in detail table but 28 branches in master still i need to show 28 branches in query and show 0 value if no data of relavent branch in detail table.**

```
select
c_name,
sum(decode(mon, 'Jan', pono, 0)) jan,
sum(decode(mon, 'Feb', pono, 0)) feb,
.....
.....
sum(decode(mon, 'Nov', pono, 0)) nov,
sum(decode(mon, 'Dec', pono, 0)) dec,
sum(decode(mon, 'Mon_Total', pono, 0)) mtotal
from (
select decode(grouping(c_name), 1, 'Total', c_name) c_name,
decode(grouping(month), 0, month, 'Mon_Total') mon, sum(po_no) pono
from t
group by cube(c_name, month)
)
group by c_name

And the result may look like:

C_NAME BR1 BR2 BR3 BR4 BR5 BR6 BR7 BR8 BR9 BR10 BR11 BR12 TOTAL_OF_ROW
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------    
----------    ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
CHKLST1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 78
CHKLST2 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 780
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c.CheckList_Name,
        b.BranchName,
        COUNT(*) ItemCount
    FROM dbo.CheckList_Detail cd
    JOIN dbo.CheckList_Master c
        ON c.CheckList_ID = cd.CheckList_ID
    JOIN dbo.Branch_Master b
        ON b.Branch_ID = cd.Branch_ID
) a
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ItemCount) FOR BranchName IN
    (
        [BR1], [BR2], [BR3], [BR4], [BR5], [BR6],
        [BR7], [BR8], [BR9], [BR10], [BR11], [BR12]
    )
) b
```

Comment: ok but I dont know how to get all the branches from master table and turn them into sql columns.?

Comment: I made it work but only one thing which is missing. At the end where you have fixed [BR1],[BR2],[BR3] etc is it possible to retrieve the Branch Names here using (select branchname from branchmaster) sort of cause if some new branches will come then in that case all the time i will have to modify the query...hope i am making sense?

Comment: There's no easy way to do that in SQL Server. You would need to use dynamic SQL or another language (C#).

Comment: dynamic SQL is a nightmare for me cause i tried dynamic SQL in other case and ASP.NET dataset didnt pick the dynamic column names as it requires physical column names in select statement instead of exec @sql ..:(